# Webview shows image as a dot in Android (tabactivity)

Tags: android, webview

I am using a `webview` to load an image from an URL, but when the webview loads, it shows the image as dot in top corner. After a zoom in/zoom out operation, I get the image at its original size.

This is my code:

```
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvcalendar);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web.setInitialScale(1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false); 
    web.loadUrl("http://www.hellotravel.com/sites/default/files/fraser-island.jpg");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `TabActivity`, it's deprecated in favor of `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
web.setInitialScale(30);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
web.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
web.loadUrl("http://www.hellotravel.com/sites/default/files/fraser-island.jpg");
```